# Add a delay for the second div keyframe

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project where I'm attempting to incorporate a delay for my second separator div. My goal is to make the second separator animation start only after the first separator animation has been completed.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.separator {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  margin-inline: 1.25rem;
  background: #09090a;
}

.separator>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, red, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00));
  animation: slide 3s ease-in infinite;
}

.group .separator:nth-of-type(2)>div {
  animation: slide 3s ease-in infinite 3s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="separator">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator">
    <div></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqdctkaj/1/)

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The code snippet works as expected for me and appears to do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Are you wanting the second item to not show while the first item is moving and vice versa? I ask because you may have a misunderstanding over delay, it only happens once at the start, after that the animation is continuous.

Comment: @DBS To clarify, the animation for the second <div> shouldn't be visible until the first one has finished, and they should be better synchronized. Additionally, both animations should be set to run infinitely not only at the start